# Why is the electromagnetic field time-constant in the static case?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

At the beginning of chapter 4 in Feynman's book on electromagnetism, he writes down Maxwell's equations:

$$\nabla\cdot E =\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\nabla\times E =-\partial_t B$$
$$\nabla\cdot B =0$$
$$c^2\nabla\times B = \partial_t E + \frac{j}{\epsilon_0}$$

> The easiest circumstance to treat is one in which nothing depends on the time—called the static case. All charges are
>   permanently fixed in space, or if they do move, they move as a steady flow in a circuit (so p and j are constant in time). In these circumstances, all of the terms in the Maxwell equations which are time derivatives of the field are zero.

That is, if $\rho(t)$ and $j(t)$ are constant at all points in space, then $\partial_t E=\partial_t B=0$. Why is that the case? I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the passage.  The static case is, by definition, the situation where nothing depends on time, so all time derivatives are zero.  $\rho$ and $j$ are constant everywhere too.

You're right that the fact that $\rho$ and $j$ are constant does not imply that $\partial_t E = \partial_t B = 0$.  As a simple counterexample, consider electromagnetic waves in a vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

Feynman's text states that the considered static condition means that **"nothing depends on time"**. Thus also also the electric and magnetic fields do not depend on time, not only the charge and current densities. In this case, there is no proof needed for that, it is an assumption.